# Specify the page where a specific endnote is

Tags: page-numbering, labels, endnotes

I would like to systematically specify the page where an endnote is. 
I could not find anything useful in the documentation.

The expected result should look like that: 
[image]

So far, I have built a newcommand which does the job but not in a very user friendly way.
MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt]{memoir} 
\usepackage{endnotes} % To write endnotes
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{refcount} % To access the page number where a label is

\newcommand{\MyEndNote}[2]{
\endnote{~page \getpagerefnumber{#2} : #1} \label{#2}
}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\MyEndNote{first endnote}{lab1}\lipsum[2]
\newpage

\lipsum[3]\MyEndNote{another endnote}{lab2}\lipsum[1]\MyEndNote{a third one }{lab3}

\newpage
\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

What I would like is to remove the second argument and generate it, somehow, automatically.

Does anyone have any idea ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The counter for `\endnote` is stepped after the endnote text has been processed. So we have to reach in the argument to increment it beforehand in order to pass the automatically generated label to `\pageref`

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt]{memoir} 
\usepackage{endnotes} % To write endnotes
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\addendnotepage}[1]{~page~#1: }

\newcommand{\MyEndNote}[1]{%
  \expandafter\endnote\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\addendnotepage\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\pageref\expandafter{%
        \the\numexpr\arabic{endnote}+1\relax:endnote%
      }%
    }%
    #1%
  }%
  \label{\arabic{endnote}:endnote}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]\MyEndNote{first endnote}\lipsum[2]

\newpage

\lipsum*[3]\MyEndNote{another endnote}\lipsum[1]\MyEndNote{a third one}

\newpage

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different implementation with the more powerful `expl3` language.

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt]{memoir} 
\usepackage{endnotes} % To write endnotes
\usepackage{xparse} % more powerful
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyEndNote}{m}
 {
  \polyv_myendnote:nf { #1 } { \int_eval:n { \arabic{endnote}+1 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \polyv_myendnote:nn
 {
  \endnote{\nobreakspace page \nobreakspace \pageref{#2:endnote}:~#1}
  \label{\arabic{endnote}:endnote}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \polyv_myendnote:nn { nf }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]\MyEndNote{first endnote}\lipsum[2]

\newpage

\lipsum*[3]\MyEndNote{another endnote}\lipsum[1]\MyEndNote{a third one}

\newpage

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

This is much more flexible; for instance, if you change the definition of `\polyv_myendnote:nn` into

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \polyv_myendnote:nn
 {
  \endnote{#1\nobreakspace(page\nobreakspace\pageref{#2:endnote})}
  \label{\arabic{endnote}:endnote}
 }
```

with no other change, you'd get

[image]

With the `f` variant, the second argument to `\polyv_myendnote:nf` is expanded prior LaTeX passes it to the main function `\polyv_myendnote:nn`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was miles away to find a solution. Better learn more about expandafter and xparse.
I implemented the second solution. Much much better looking.
Back to writing !

Comment: By the way, I don't suppose there's an easy solution to group the endnotes by page. 
Page 1 :
1. first note
2. second
Page 3.
3. third
4. fourth
Page 4:
X. and so on 

It would need to modify the code of the command \theendnotes,  right ?

Comment: @PolyV Possibly with reprocessing the `.ent` file.

Comment: I should try that when I'll feel more fluent in LaTeX. So far, your solution is making my work much more easier already.